# not able to get Album art for songs

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface, layout

I am a newbie to android app development. I want to add cover art or album art for every song playing in the music player. I have tried many methods reading from stack overflow but none are working for me. It seems like I am missing on some basic concepts. I am getting an error . I dont know how to remove this error. I am getting error at

```
getAlbumart(songs);
```

It says cannot resolve symbol songs

Can anyone help me with this ?

This is the code

```
    public void abc(){
        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        setContentView(R.layout.playlist);

        ListView mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        mMusicList = getAudioList();

        ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mMusicList);
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                                    long arg3) {

                try {


                    playSong(mAudioPath[arg2]);
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private String[] getAudioList() {
        final Cursor mCursor = getContentResolver().query(
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                new String[]{MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA}, null, null,
                "LOWER(" + MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + ") ASC");

        int count = mCursor.getCount();

        String[] songs = new String[count];
        mAudioPath = new String[count];
        int i = 0;
        if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                songs[i] = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
                mAudioPath[i] = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
                i++;
            } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
        }

        mCursor.close();
        return songs;
    }

    private void playSong(String path) throws IllegalArgumentException,
            IllegalStateException, IOException {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_audio_player);


        Log.d("ringtone", "playSong :: " + path);

        mMediaPlayer.reset();
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
        mMediaPlayer.prepare();
        mMediaPlayer.start();


        getAlbumart(songs);

    }
    public Bitmap getAlbumart(Long album_id)
    {
        Bitmap bm = null;
        try
        {
            final Uri sArtworkUri = Uri
                    .parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");

            Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, album_id);
            ParcelFileDescriptor pfd =  Bacon1.this.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");

            if (pfd != null)
            {
                FileDescriptor fd = pfd.getFileDescriptor();
                bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fd);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return bm;
    }

}
```

Comment: i think `songs` may be null or not set. I dont see any reference inside `private void playSong`

Comment: Can you help me how to get album art for songs? everything else is working fine in my app

Comment: How do I set songs ?